# Word2Vec Python similarity

Tags: python, similarity, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I made a word embedding with this code:

```
with open("text.txt",'r') as longFile:
        sentences = []
        single= []
        for line in longFile:
            for word in line.split(" "):
                single.append(word)
            sentences.append(single)
    model = Word2Vec(sentences,workers=4, window=5)
```

I want now to calculate the similarity between two word and see what are the neighbours of them.
What is the difference between `model["word"]`,`model.wv.most_similar()`, `model.similar_by_vector()` and `model.similarity()`?
Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Maybe we should tag `gensim` here, because it is the library we are using

If you want to find the neighbours of both you can use
`model.wv.most_similar()` this will give you a dict (top n) for each word and its similarities for a given string (word). This method will calculate the cosine similarity between the word-vectors.

Note that the other methods you mentioned are deprecated in `3.4.0`, use `model.wv.similarity()` and `model.wv.similar_by_vector()` instead.

You can also use `model.wv.similar_by_vector()` to do the exact same thing but by passing a vector. Eg. `model["woman"]` would give you such a vector. Actually if you look at the implementation, all the method does is call `most_similar()`

```
def similar_by_vector(self, vector, topn=10, restrict_vocab=None):
   return self.most_similar(positive=[vector], topn=topn, restrict_vocab=restrict_vocab)
```

Same goes for the `similar_by_word()` method. I actually don't know why these methods exist in the first place.

To find a similarity measure between exactly two words you can either use
`model.wv.similarity()` to find the cosine similarity or `model.wv.distance()` to find the cosine distance between the two.

To answer your actual question, I would simply compute the similarity between the two instead of comparing the results of `most_similar()`.

I hope this helps. Look at the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) or the source files to get even more information, the code documentation is pretty good I think.